# Read Spring Boot application properties in interface

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-lambda, properties-file

I have a Spring Boot app which calls some AWS Lambda, like this:

```
public interface AWSLambdaInvoke {

    @LambdaFunction(functionName = "my-aws-lambda")
    LambdaOutput invokeLambda(LambdaInput lambdaInput);
}
```

Since I have both prod and dev environment, I would like to have the function name as a property in application.yml file or something similar, so that I can choose which lambda to call depending on my env.
Is there a way to achieve this from the interfaces in Java 16?

Comment: No there isn't. The `@LamdaFunction` annotation doesn't proces SpEL expression in the `functionName`.

Comment: Oh, that's too bad. Is this info in the documentation? Any other way to have the function name injected dynamically?

Comment: No. Support has to be placed in the annotation processor if it isn't in the processor there is no way to do this.

Comment: Found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786380/determine-the-aws-lambda-name-on-runtime-in-java/47259414) . Thankfully it was implemented.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine the AWS lambda name on runtime in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786380/determine-the-aws-lambda-name-on-runtime-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that since version `"1.10.51"` there is a functionality named as `LambdaFunctionNameResolver`, you can read more about it here:

[https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-lambda/LambdaFunctionNameResolver.java](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-lambda/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/invoke/LambdaFunctionNameResolver.java)

you may write something like this:

```
 AWSLambdaInvokeService lambdaInvoke = 
 LambdaInvokerFactory.builder().lambdaClient(AWSLambdaClientBuilder.defaultClient())
.lambdaFunctionNameResolver((method, annotation, config) 
-> generalConfigHelper.getString("name_of_your_function")).build(AWSLambdaInvokeService.class);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I used in the end and it works perfectly. I didn't update mu question, I'll just set it as closed and accept your answer in any case. Thank you for your time!